# Is it possible to set local storage size of a WebBrowser control?

Tags: html, windows-phone-7, local-storage

I'd like to embed a `WebBrowser` in my application but have control over how much local storage the websites can use (I want to increase that limit, 5MB is too little for me). Is it possible? I only saw IsScriptEnable and IsGeolocationEnabled, but nothing related to the cache size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, no. The 5MB limit is pertaining to HTML5 and is put in place so that one website/domain does not fill up all available space.